# Clicking the SharePoint List Web Part title link opens two tabs

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting

If you set a `defaultClick` action in JSON for a column in a list, two tabs of details will open in the List web part.

Only Chrome and Edge on iPad and iPhone. Safari is fine.

There is no problem with PC.

I contacted MS support, but they said they couldn't help.

However, a similar phenomenon occurred on the terminal of the person in charge of MS.

Is there a workaround?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent":"Test",
  "customRowAction":{
    "action":"defaultClick"
  }
}
```